# python program can't get sys.argv[1]

Tags: python-3.x

this is my code

```
def main():  
    try:
        msg = sys.stdin.read()
        logger.info('-------------------')
        logger.info(len(sys.argv))
        logger.info(str(sys.argv))
        logger.info(str(type(sys.argv[1])))
        logger.error(sys.argv[1])
        logger.info(sys.argv[0])
        logger.info('=================')
        #rcli = redis.Redis(host=config.REDIS_HOST, db=config.REDIS_DB)
        #rcli.lpush('alert_msg', sys.argv[1])
        #rcli.lpush('alert_msg', msg)
        #Alert().process(alert_msg)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("[alert] encountered error: {0}".format(e))
```

and this is my log

[logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3clqe.png)

why `logger.error(sys.argv[1])` logs nothing? does anyone have any idea

Comment: Maybe you didn't pass your script any arguments on the command line.

Comment: How did you run this script? I.e. `python app.py randomArgument`
Dummy question, have you included `import sys`? Also, if you raise the exception, `raise e`, maybe it'll provide more clear error message.

Comment: how do you explain logger.info(len(sys.argv))   logged 2 into the log file@RedCricket

Comment: #!/bin/bash
read msg
python3 /home/facility/alert/alert.py $msg
echo $msg >> /tmp/test.log                                                    @joegalaxian

Comment: I don't think the problem is in `sys.argv[1]`. Try `print(sys.argv[1])`, I'm sure I'll work.

You could config the `logger` to automatically print to a file, instead of redirecting the output to the `test.log`. Docs.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html

Also, double check the `>>` to ensure you're redirecting both output (`INFO`s) and errors (`ERROR`s).

Comment: I think the error may be on how you call the script. I'd suggest making use of the file handler that `logger` supports and forget about the rest.